# Orthogonal matrix

Tags: statistics, euclidean-geometry, orthogonality

I am given that the vectors $x$ and $x'$ have the same Euclidean length and $Qx=x'$ where $Q=I-\frac{2uu^T}{\|u\|^2}$ and $u=x-x'$.

I need to show that $Q$ is orthogonal but I don't know how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the transpose, we have 
$$ Q^t = I^t - \frac{2uu^t}{\def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}\norm u^2} = Q, $$
hence, $Q$ is symmetric. As, moreover 
\begin{align*}
  Q^2 &= I - 4\frac{uu^t}{\norm u^2} + 4\frac{uu^tuu^t}{\norm u^4}\\
      &= I - 4\frac{uu^t}{\norm u^2} + 4 \frac{u\norm u^2 u^t}{\norm u^4}\\
      &= I - 4 \frac{uu^t}{\norm u^2} + 4 \frac{uu^t}{\norm u^2}\\
      &= I,
\end{align*}
$Q$ fulfills $QQ^t = Q^tQ = Q^2 = I$, hence, $Q$ is orthogonal.

Comment: Why when you square Q, you have -4..+4.. and not just the +4.. ?

Comment: Yes. Denote for brevity $U := \frac{2uu^t}{\|u\|^2}$, then $Q = I - U$ and $Q^2 = (I - U)^2 = I - 2U + U^2$.